# jquery div display according to url?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have following code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#div1").hide();
            $("#div2").hide();
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">This is first Div</div>
    <div id="div2">Welcome At 2nd Div </div>
</body>
</html>
```

the url is index.html. How I can show the #div1 if url is like index.html#div1 and #div2 if url is like index.html#div2

Comment: People, read again: "..How I can *show*.."

Comment: Are you quite sure you want URLs like `index.html#div1`? Hardly the friendliest URL to bookmark. Why not have friendlier hashes then translate these to particular DIVs in the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function){
    $("div[id^=div]").hide();
    var loc = window.location.href;
    if( loc.indexOf( '#' ) >= 0 ) {
        hash = loc.substr( loc.indexOf('#') + 1 ); // output: div1, div2 etc..
        $('#'+hash).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Good old (yet new!) CSS selector matching! :-D

Comment: @thecodeparadox np, altho i dont think this is cross browser, isn't .hash a chrome feature?  I'm at work so i can't really test that

Comment: just in case that is not cross browser and you need it, keep in mind you can use `window.location.pathname` to do something like `window.location.pathname.match(/#div1/) ? $("#div1).show() : $("#div2).show();`

Comment: yes it working fine but code 1 location.hash is not working the code 2 is working fine

Comment: one more thing is hash is always returning something for example if there is no hash its returning complete url instead of returning false

Comment: @thecodeparadox its not returning empty string when its empty it returns complete url of page and when there is hash it returns hash